# Unable to select more than one armature single bone in edit mode

Tags: armature, bones, edit-mode

I have created two armature single bone and I need to parent one of them to another. For doing this I am trying to select both of them in edit mode but in vein. I am able to select them in object mode but not in edit mode. The reason I am selecting this in edit mode is because both of the single bones has many extruded single bone meshes and I need to select only the master one from which all the other are extruded.

Thanks,

Varun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to join the bones in object mode <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, then you can go to edit mode to parent them.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick response gladys. It worked liked a charm. Saved my day.